# slice field in struct is overwritten with last value

Tags: go

I have a function that basically gathers a list of users from a mongoDB database, then stores those users in a struct.

```
// GetUsers gets all local users from a MongoDB
func GetUsers() {
    var decode structs.User
    logging.Info("Gathering Users from DB")
    collection := mongoclient.Database.Collection("LocalUsers")
    cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{})
    if err != nil {
        logging.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("In users - Getting data from MongoDB: %s", err))
    }

    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
        // create a value into which the single document can be decoded
        err := cur.Decode(&decode)
        if err != nil {
            logging.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("In users - Error decoding results: %s", err))
        }
        // if there is nothing in the database dont try create a User
        if decode.Username != "" {
            structs.LocalUsers[decode.Username] = decode
            fmt.Printf("stored: %+v\n", structs.LocalUsers[decode.Username].DcList)
            fmt.Printf("struct: %+v\n", structs.LocalUsers[decode.Username].DcList)
        }
        fmt.Printf("in get stored: %+v\n", structs.LocalUsers)
    }
    cur.Close(context.TODO())
}
```

The struct in question

```
//LocalUsers is just a slice of all users gathered from DB
var LocalUsers = make(map[string]User)

// User describes a user
type User struct {
    Username string
    Password string
    FullName string
    Email    string
    Role     string
    DcList   []string
}
```

This concept works in other parts of my code, however in here it seems that from testing when  insert objects into mongo, everything works as expected. I get the results I expect etc.
Its when I actually restart the application that I noticed that all information is as I expect, except the DcList slice. It's always overwritten with the last item in the loop. I did a few tests and I just cannot make why this is happening?

```
stored: {Username:Admin Password:peopleeater FullName:Administrator Email:admin@here.com Role:Admin DcList:[]}
struct: {Username:Admin Password:peopleeater FullName:Administrator Email:admin@here.com Role:Admin DcList:[]}
stored: {Username:bob Password:password FullName:bob Email:bob@here.com Role:View DcList:[eriks]}
struct: {Username:bob Password:password FullName:bob Email:bob@here.com Role:View DcList:[eriks]}
stored: {Username:test Password:test1 FullName:test1 Email:test1@here.com Role:View DcList:[test1]}
struct: {Username:test Password:test1 FullName:test1 Email:test1@here.com Role:View DcList:[test1]}
stored: {Username:test2 Password:test2 FullName:test2 Email:test2@here.com Role:View DcList:[test2]}
struct: {Username:test2 Password:test2 FullName:test2 Email:test2@here.com Role:View DcList:[test2]}
stored: {Username:test3 Password:test3 FullName:test3 Email:test3@here.com Role:View DcList:[test1]}
struct: {Username:test3 Password:test3 FullName:test3 Email:test3@here.com Role:View DcList:[test1]}
in get stored: map[Admin:{Username:Admin Password:P@$$w0rd FullName:Administrator Email:admin@here.com Role:Admin DcList:[]} bob:{Username:bob Password:password FullName:bob Email:bob@here.com Role:View DcList:[test1]} test:{Username:test Password:test1 FullName:test1 Email:test1@here.com Role:View DcList:[test1]} test2:{Username:test2 Password:test2 FullName:test2 Email:test2@here.com Role:View DcList:[test1]} test3:{Username:test3 Password:test3 FullName:test3 Email:test3@here.com Role:View DcList:[test1]}]
```

I have thought about maybe I should initialize the slice? However I have not seemed to have to do this in the past so I'm confused where here at this stage it seems to happen? I know its something simple I'm missing

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, it shows `in get stored` being printed inside the loop but the output looks like it was outside the loop. Don't reuse the same temporary object into which to decode. The primitive types are being overwritten, but the slice keeps the same underlying array. Move `var decode structs.User` inside the for loop. I say this knowing nothing about the mongo `Decode` implementation, just a guess from the behavior.

Comment: facepalm.... you are right, that resolved it